# What is the point of the httponly ss-tok bearerToken cookie in ServiceStack Authentication

Tags: typescript, authentication, cookies, servicestack

I understand from security perspective the concept of an httponly flag for the value of Set-Cookie Response header and preventing XSS attacks.

What I do not understand is, what is ServiceStack doing with the "ss-tok" cookie that saves the bearerToken.

According to [ServiceStack documentation](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#request-jwt-cookie-is-set-on-authentication) I can convert to a stateless session by issuing a stateless JWT Cookie like so:

```
var authResponse = client.Send(new Authenticate {
    provider = "credentials",
    UserName = username,
    Password = password,
    UseTokenCookie = true
});
```

The UseTokenCookie is set to true. And the httponly "ss-tok" cookie is created upon successful authentication.

Yet I cannot seem to use this token cookie, stored with the name "ss-tok", for anything. I cannot retrieve it with Javascript obviously and I cannot seem to get it to be sent in `JsonServiceClient` requests.

[image]

My ServiceStack resource microservices do not ever receive the value of "ss-tok" in any secure request. I have to explicitly set the bearerToken for any secure request.

I have  to explicitly pass the bearerToken or refreshToken with my `JsonServiceClient` as stated in the [ServiceStack documentation on this matter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client#authenticating-using-jwt).

I must be doing something wrong, [I thought this documentation](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#sending-jwt-using-cookies) was the part I was missing, this code here:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
client.SetCookie("ss-tok", jwtToken);
```

But this code makes no sense actually, since the value of "ss-tok" is not being sent to my resource microservices, I have to explicitly set bearerToken value like I said earlier:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
client.bearerToken = jwtToken;
```

This means I will have to store jwtToken in my own cookie value because my app will need to create multiple instances of JsonServiceClient in different areas of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Cookie that holds the JWT Token which [does get sent on subsequent requests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/7ad888b4d7ab50fc627eefc20369ad3178d64986/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/UseCases/JwtAuthProviderTests.cs#L275) like any other Cookie.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake thinking ss-tok was not being passed with my requests

Comment: do you think this was cross domain origin issue? I was trying to connect from a localhost.com app to a microservice running on a server myapiendpoint.com

Comment: @BrianOgden Cookies only apply to the domain of the original request so if you want to use the JWT across multiple domains you'll need to [explicitly set the BearerToken on the Service Client](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#converting-an-existing-authenticated-session-into-a-jwt-token).

Comment: Does ConvertSessionToToken require a ServiceStack User Auth Repository to work? I am using a legacy database User table currently

Comment: @BrianOgden No it's converting the current Authenticated UserSession (stored in the registered ICacheClient) into a JWT Token, then removing it from the cache unless [PreserveSession = true](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#converting-an-existing-authenticated-session-into-a-jwt-token).