# Use the JWT tokens across multiple domains with Typescript JsonServiceClient - ServiceStack

Tags: typescript, servicestack

After getting answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419921/what-is-the-point-of-the-httponly-ss-tok-bearertoken-cookie-in-servicestack-auth), I realized that I have a cross-domain issue with the httponly flagged ServiceStack bearerToken Cookie not being sent to my resource microservices on different domains.

ServiceStack's documentation explains how to solve this problem in their documentation [here](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#converting-an-existing-authenticated-session-into-a-jwt-token).

I having trouble implementing a Typescript version of the code sample in ServiceStack's documentation. I am guess that the sample code in the documentation is C#.

Here is my Typescript code with comments:

```
import { JsonServiceClient, IReturn } from 'servicestack-client';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
//dtos generated by myauthservice/types
import { GetAccessToken, ConvertSessionToToken, ConvertSessionToTokenResponse } from './dtos'
import { AppModule } from '../../app.module';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class JsonServiceClientAuth extends JsonServiceClient {

    private router: Router;
    private authClient: JsonServiceClient;

    constructor(baseUrl: string) {
        console.log('JsonServiceClientAuth.baseUrl', baseUrl);
        super(baseUrl);
        //Router is not injected via the contructor because clients of JsonServiceClientAuth need to create instances of it
        this.router = AppModule.injector.get(Router);
        this.authClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:5006");

        this.onAuthenticationRequired = async () => {
            console.log('JsonServiceClientAuth.onAuthenticationRequired()');
            console.log('An API is not receiving the bearerToken being redirected to Login');
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        };
    }

    get<T>(request: IReturn<T> | string, args?: any): Promise<T> {
        return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {

            //cross domain issue here, ss-tok httponly Cookie will not be sent to the Resource Service
            //ConvertSessionToToken per Service Stacks documentation: http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#converting-an-existing-authenticated-session-into-a-jwt-token

            //but send expects 2-4 argumments, one being the method name
            //the Typecript send will not use the dto ConvertSessionToToken request and get the url
            //var tokenResponse = this.send(new ConvertSessionToToken())

            console.log('this.bearToken', this.bearerToken); //undefined
            //so try JsonServiceClient.get
            this.authClient.get(new ConvertSessionToToken())
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('ConvertSessionToToken.res', res); 
                    console.log('this.bearToken', this.bearerToken); //undefined
                    //next problem there is no function getTokenCookie in Typescript that I can find, not in the dtos and not in JsonServiceClient
                    //var jwtToken = this.getTokenCookie(); //From ss-tok Cookie

                    //maybe this will work?
                    //super.setBearerToken(this.bearerToken)
                    super.get(request).then(res => {
                        console.log('suger.get.res', res);
                        resolve(res);
                    }, msg => {
                        console.log('suger.get.msg', res);
                        reject(msg)
                    })
                    .catch(ex => {
                        console.log('suger.get.ex', ex);
                        reject(ex);
                    });
                }, msg => {
                    console.log('ConvertSessionToToken.msg', msg);
                    reject(msg);
                })
                .catch(ex =>{
                    console.log('ConvertSessionToToken.ex', ex);
                    reject(ex);
                });
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you implementing a Custom JsonServiceClient? Just use the existing `bearerToken` and `refreshToken` properties on the existing `JsonServiceClient` which already has built-in support for sending JWT Bearer Tokens and using Refresh Tokens to re-fetch expired JWT Tokens.

You can check out [client.auth.spec.ts](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/blob/master/tests/client.auth.spec.ts) for examples of supported behavior.

Comment: I have looked through all these test methods in client.auth.spec.ts, I have cross domain resource APIs so JsonServiceClient requests are not including ss-tok. I have no refreshToken because I am using a custom legacy database and I cannot access the httponly ss-tok with Javascript. I do not know how to make an authorized call to a cross-domain resource api for a user that already authenticated. In a quite a few of the client.auth.spec.ts tests you either createJwt based on mock userAuthId, email or you have a username/password to authorize, I already have a bearerToken, the user has logged in

Comment: you said "you'll need to explicitly set the BearerToken on the Service Client" for my cross domain resource request to work so I am implementing a Custom JsonServiceClient to hide those implementation details from areas of my app that use JsonServiceClient

Comment: See my [updated answer with the new IUserSessionSource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403514/85785) which lets you be able to use RefreshTokens without an AuthRepository. But  that's not related to this, you can't use the JWT in a token Cookie across domains but you can use the `bearerToken` property which sends the token using the Authorization HTTP Header. So don't set `UseTokenCookie=true` then [access the BearerToken from the AuthenticateResponse](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#retrieve-token-with-api-key) and use it to populate each different `JsonServiceClient` instance.

Comment: Should I store the BearerToken property value of AuthenticateResponse in a cookie? I will not have the username/password soon enough so I can't keep calling authClient.Send(new Authenticate()).BearerToken; every time I create a new JsonServiceClients obviously.

Comment: @BrianOgden No don't use cookies, just populate the `bearerToken` property of each `JsonServiceClient` and reuse the instances for each different site.

Comment: A Singleton pattern for each JsonServiceClient instance?

Comment: Or at least a Singleton for the auth JsonServiceClient right?

Comment: @BrianOgden It's up to you how you want to maintain your instances, but you can reuse instances. If you prefer you can register the BearerToken in a single place, e.g. `state.BearerToken` and use a factory to retrieve a new `JsonServiceClient` that's populated with the url and BearerToken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159526/discussion-between-brian-ogden-and-mythz).

Comment: @BrianOgden Please ask in new questions/comments, don't use chat as any info gets lost.

Comment: so storing the bearerToken/refreshToken in some instance state store in my app, means, when app exits/shutdown, the user will need to authenticate again when the app opens next time correct?

Comment: @BrianOgden How you store the token is all up to you, the JWT is a stateless token that's all embedded in the token (i.e. requires no server state). So you could store it in localStorage if you want to retrieve it across App sessions.